# Can't update user information in Laravel

Tags: laravel, crud

On my current project (a school management system) I want to give admins the ability to register users. Admins can create courses and subjects for example, which I've managed to do using resource controllers. However, I thought I could do the same for users, since the process appears the same to me. That is: I can show, edit, create, update and delete users.

However, I've run into several problems so far. Right now I can create users, but not update them.

Here's my code:

web.php

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'admin'])->group(function () {

  Route::get('/admin', 'HomeController@admin');

  Route::post('register', 'UserController@store');

  Route::resources([
      'admin/cursos' => 'CursoController',
      'admin/turmas' => 'TurmaController',
      'admin/semestres' => 'SemestreController',
      'admin/materias' => 'MateriaController',
      'admin/usuarios' => 'UserController',
  ]);

});
```

UserController.php

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
  $rules = array(
    'name'      => 'required|string|max:255',
    'email'     => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
    'role'      => 'required|string',
    'password'  => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
  );

  $validator = validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

  if ($validator->fails()) {
    // return dd();
    return Redirect::to('/admin/usuarios/' . $id . '/edit')
    ->withErrors($validator);
  } else {
    // store
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->name       = Input::get('name');
    $user->email      = Input::get('email');
    $user->role       = Input::get('role');
    $user->password   = Input::get('password');
    $user->save();

    // redirect
    Session::flash('message', 'Sucesso!');
    return Redirect::to('/admin/usuarios');
  }

}
```

Validation fails every time I try to update user information. What exactly is going on here? I'm relatively new to Laravel, so I'm a bit lost now.

Comment: `Validation fails` - how, exactly? What fails, what is the message?  For all we know you may be leaving `name` blank on your update form, so validation is correcty failing.  Not enough info here to help without guessing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the request is failing when a user is trying to update their information without changing the email address, you need additional logic to ignore the id for user associated with the email.

> Sometimes, you may wish to ignore a given ID during the unique check. For example, consider an "update profile" screen that includes the user's name, e-mail address, and location. Of course, you will want to verify that the e-mail address is unique. However, if the user only changes the name field and not the e-mail field, you do not want a validation error to be thrown because the user is already the owner of the e-mail address.
>
> To instruct the validator to ignore the user's ID, we'll use the Rule class to fluently define the rule. In this example, we'll also specify the validation rules as an array instead of using the | character to delimit the rules:

```
Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
    ],
]);
```

Applied to your set of validation rules it would look like:

```
$rules = array(
    'name'      => 'required|string|max:255',
    'email'     => [
        'required', 
        'string', 
        'email, 
        'max:255', 
        Rule::unique('users')->ignore(auth()->id())
     ],
    'role'      => 'required|string',
    'password'  => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to except the User ID ($id) in email validation, since u use "unique" rule.

you can check the guide in here
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique